# Mongoose - Pre Save Increment Function not triggering

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a new document within my DB and before saving that I want to increment a variable but the pre save method does not execute.

**Proposal Schema:**

```
const Counter = require('./counter');

proposalSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

  let doc = this;

  Counter.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: 'entityId'},{$inc: { seq: 1}},{"upsert": true,"new": true  }, function(error, counter){

    if(error){
        return next(error);
    }

        doc.proposalNo = counter.seq;
        next();
  });
});
```

**Counter Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const counterSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    seq: {type: Number, default: 5000}

});

mongoose.model('Counter', counterSchema);
```

I get a `Internal Server Error 500`.

**No matter what I do the increment won't work. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing proposalSchema with counterSchema

Comment: How so? Can explain a bit more? Im trying to increment my `CounterSchema` before I save my `ProposalSchema`

Comment: The code you have shared you are declaring counterSchema and then you are using proposalSchema. I think some code is missing.

Comment: ah. CounterSchema is in a completely different file and is exported into the proposalSchema.